# Objective C, iOS, how do I attach a couple of int variables to UIImageView which is part of an IBOutletCollection?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, nsarray

I need to keep track of some image views which can be dragged around the screen and located within other images views. For example footballs in goals. I'd like to do this by having some extra properties attached to the footballs, current goal and times seen in the goal.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) 
    NSArray *multipleFootballs;
```

I figure, that I have to create a super class.
Although I'm not sure the best way to do this ?

EDIT3 : Thanks nick, but how do I then access a instance property ?

```
@interface FootballImageView : UIImageView {
    int intCurrentGoal;
}
@property (readwrite) int intCurrentGoal;

@implementation FootballImageView
@synthesize intCurrentGoal;

-(id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        // do your initialization here...
    }
    return self; 
}

@end

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for (id football in multipleFootballs) {

    //if ([[touches anyObject] intCurrentGoal] == 0) {
    //if (football.intCurrentGoal == 0) {
```

Comment: have you synthesized your property? football.intCurrentGoal can only be used if you have written a getter method or synethized one. `[touches anyObject]` is something completely different: it'll return a UITouch object in this case.

Comment: don't use retain, copy or assign for primitive types! Remove the assign. And your initializer is not complete. I'll add a cleaner version in my answer...

Comment: I've added a reply for edit 3 in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy:

- Create a new subclass inheriting from UIImageView, let's call it MyImageView
- Add your custom instance variables you need to the header
- Choose as class for the old UIImageViews the new MyImageView in interface builder (Identity Tab)
- Change `IBOutletCollection(UIImageView)` to `IBOutletCollection(MyImageView)`

-

```
- (id)init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        // do your initialization here...
    }
    return self; 
}
```

#### Reply for edit 3

The problem you are facing is the anonymous type (id) you are using in touchesBegan. Put in a check like this:

```
for (FootballImageView *football in multipleFootballs) {
    if(football.intCurrentGoal == 0) {
        football.intCurrentGoal++;
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Jules By assigning a value to your property. Corrected that. You set a value to intCurrentGoal by assigning to it. However I don't think that's what your question was pointing at, right?

Comment: @Jules you can write the loop like my updated answer shows, as long as you know that `multipleFootballs` will contain `FootballImageViews` only. What kind of warning do you see?

Comment: @Jules, yes it was a type, it's the big F, it should be isKindOfClass, however you can alter your loop like in the updated answer.

Comment: @Jules can you give us some code where you'd like to set the value?

Comment: @Jules Have you imported the header of the FootballImageView? And in what class is your touchesBegan actually?

Comment: @Jules I am not sure how I can help you at the moment. I've created a simple MyImageView class witht the property and a multipleFootballs array and the code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

The usual (and good) advice is that you should avoid keeping state in view objects. Attributes like times seen in goal and current goal should be part of your data model, not attached to your views. There are lots of good reasons for this, but they mostly boil down to two big points:

1. Mixing state with views will make things unnecessarily complicated.
2. Cocoa Touch is designed with an expectation that apps will adopt the MVC paradigm.

As an example of the first point, consider what happens when the user switches away from the main game screen to change settings, answer a phone call, etc. As I see it, you have three choices: a) preserve all the views even though they're not being displayed that you can maintain the app's state; b) save the state from the views before releasing the views; c) prevent the user from switching away from the game. Neither (a) nor (c) seem like good ideas, and if you take the MVC approach you get (b) for free.

Instead, create a data model that can represent all the aspects of your game. You can use standard classes like NSDictionary and NSSet, or classes of your own design like Football and Pitch, or (most likely) a combination. Then create a game controller which observes changes to the relevant model objects and makes changes in the corresponding views.

Comment: Oh I hadn't realised that the values wouldn't be kept. I'm looking for a simple approach. I'm a bit concerned that i would be out of my depth with implementing some of your sugestions. I did consider a very low tech approach but this would a silly. I find it hard to visualise the best approach without seeing examples, which are hard to come by.

Comment: "Data model" might sound inimidating, but your model can be as simple as you want to make it. Check out [SeismicXML](http://tinyurl.com/4ymdp5x)'s [Earthquake](http://tinyurl.com/6ekrnok) class -- it's really just a container for the values that describe an earthquake.

Comment: I take it your just using this an example and dong mean to use XML. Just seems a big excessive?

Comment: Right -- forget about the XML part. The data model for the app is just an array of Earthquake objects. Yours might be an array of Football objects, or a dictionary containing arrays of Football and Goal objects, or whatever makes sense for what you're doing.

Comment: So how would you suggest I link the model items with my view controls?